# Getting DataExtRet from QuickBooks SDK

Tags: quickbooks

I am performing an invoice query using the QuickBooks SDK and I'd like to pull back custom fields at the item level as well. The request I am sending is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceQueryRq>
      <RefNumber>8</RefNumber>
      <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
      <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
    </InvoiceQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I get a successful response, however, there are no `<DataExtRet>` elements with my custom field information. I can get this data if I do an item query with the `<OwnerID>` element however, according to IDN, I should be able to get these custom fields in an invoice query as well. I am testing my queries using SDK Tester Plus 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template being used did not contain the "Serial Number" UDF I was looking for. Adding this to the invoice template and then calling InvoicequeryRq pulled back the information I was looking for.